# A closed manifold with a subset with the same ring cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Is there an example of a closed manifold $M$ with a proper subset $A\subset M$ such  the inclusion $i:A \to M$   gives a ring isomorphism $i^{*}$ between $\mathbb{Z}$-cohomologies?

In this question $A$ is merely a proper subset.(not necessarily compact, not necessarily submanifold)

Comment: $*\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Adam Note that a closed manifold (as usual) is a compact manifold without boundary!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose for simplicity that $M$ is connected and orientable.  Choose a point $x\in M\setminus  A$, and a closed disc $U$ centred at $x$.  We can use the chart to deform $i$ into a homotopic map $j$ such that $j(A)\subseteq M\setminus\text{int}(U)$.  Collapsing the complement of $U$ gives a map $p$ from $M$ to the one-point compactification $U\cup\{\infty\}$, which is homeomorphic to $S^n$.  It is standard that the resulting map $p^*\colon\mathbb{Z}=\widetilde{H}^n(S^n)\to H^n(M)$ is an isomorphism, but $pj$ is constant, so the map $i^*p^*=j^*p^*=(pj)^*$ is zero, so $i^*$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: I did not assume that $A$ is closed(It is possible that $A$ is dense. so we can not choose the open disc $U$.

Comment: This does not make much difference.  I have modified the argument.

Comment: In the non orientable case, a similar argument shows that the induced homomorphism $H_n(A;\mathbb{Z}_2)\to H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is trivial. On the other hand, if the inclusion induced an isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, it would also be an isomorphism with any coefficients (universal coefficient formula).