# Cohomologically minimal spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $X$ be  a compact connected Hausdorff topological space.

We  say $X$ is a cohomologicaly minimal space, briefly  CM space, if $X$ satisfies  the following property:

"For every proper subset  $A\subset X$ with the inclusion map $i:A \to X$, $i^*$ is  NOT a ring isomorphism between $H^*(X,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(A,\mathbb{Z})$"

In the other word, $A$ is the only subset of $A$ whose inclusion gives a ring isomorphism cohomology.

Examples; All closed manifolds (see [A closed manifold with a subset with the same ring cohomology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156228/a-closed-manifold-with-a-subset-with-the-same-ring-cohomology) )

Non Examples: Closed disc, figure 8,...etc.

My question

> Is the product of two CM spaces, a CM space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me say that $X$ has property $CM'$ if for every field $F$ and every point $a\in X$, the map $H_*(X\setminus a;F)\to H_*(X;F)$ is injective but not surjective.  Then orientable closed manifolds have $CM'$, and $CM'$ implies $CM$.  Now suppose that $X$ and $Y$ both have $CM'$.  After noting that 
$$ (X\times Y)\setminus (a,b) = ((X\setminus a)\times Y) \cup 
                                (X\times (Y\setminus b))
$$
we can use the Kunneth isomorphism and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to see that $X\times Y$ also has $CM'$.  (I switched to using homology to ensure that Kunneth works in a straightforward way even if the spaces have infinitely generated homology.) I think that a similar approach can be made to work for non-orientable manifolds if we modify the definition of $CM'$ to distinguish between fields that do or do not have characteristic $2$.  Thus, to make progress you should investigate whether there are any spaces that have $CM$ but not $CM'$.

Incidentally, contrary to your list of non-examples, I think that the figure 8 has $CM'$ (and therefore $CM$).

Comment: Thank you. Yes. It was my typos. Obviously figure 8 is a CM space. A question:Can the homology or cohomology  version of Kunneth formula be applied for space which are not necessarily a CW complex?

Comment: Let $X$ be two closed (non-zero-dimensional) manifolds connected by an interval. Then $X$ has $CM$ but not $CM'$

Comment: One can use similar arguments to show the similar but incomparable statement that if $X\backslash \{a\}$ into $X$ and $Y\backslash \{b\}$ into $Y$ do not induce isomorphisms and $a$ and $b$ each has a contractible neighborhood, then the inclusion of $X\times Y\backslash (a,b)$ into $X\times Y$ cannot induce an isomorphism.